# How can I write a trigger that gets the last inserted row into the table?

Tags: postgresql

I was to populate a field `is_continued_post` if some conditions are true about the previously inserted row into the table (it's the same user, and it's `inserted_at` is less than N mins from the new rows inserted_at).

When a new comment is inserted into the database. I want to get the last comment (with the same `post_id`) that was inserted, then check that the old rows user_id are the same as the new rows user_id, and that the old row was inserted less than 2 mins before the new row. If this is true, I want to flip a boolean on the new row to true before inserting it.

Is this possible with Postgresql triggers? Or is there a better way to do this?

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_message_cont()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  old := (SELECT m0.user_id, m0.inserted_at FROM messages AS m0 WHERE (m0.post_id = NEW.post_id) ORDER BY m0.inserted_at DESC LIMIT 1);
  NEW.is_continued := CASE
      WHEN old is NULL THEN FALSE
      WHEN old.user_id = NEW.user_id AND ((NEW.inserted_at - old.inserted_at) < 120) THEN TRUE
  END;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible, but only if you have a column in the table that allows you to identify the last inserted row. The order of insertion is not reflected in the table as such.

So introduce a column

```
inserted_at timestamp with time zone DEFAULT clock_timestamp() NOT NULL
```

An index on `(post_id, inserted_at)` will make the query fast.

The whole trigger could look like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_message_cont() RETURNS trigger AS
$$BEGIN
   SELECT user_id IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NEW.user_id INTO NEW.is_continued
   FROM messages
   WHERE post_id = NEW.post_id
     AND inserted_at > NEW.inserted_at - INTERVAL '120 seconds'
   ORDER BY inserted_at DESC
   LIMIT 1;

   -- if no previous row was found:
   IF NEW.is_continued IS NULL THEN
      NEW.is_continued = FALSE;
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_message_cont BEFORE INSERT ON messages
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_message_cont();
```

Comment: I'm new to writing Trigger queries. This is what I wrote out that should work, but I get an error `subquery must return only one column` (see edit above)

Comment: I have updated my answer with how the trigger function could look.

Comment: **Never** store timestamps as numeric values.

Comment: Awesome. This works like I was looking for. Only issue, if there's no previous message, it returns nil instead of false. Could I just add `NEW.is_contiunted := NEW.is_continued OR false;`?

Comment: I fixed it with this before `RETURN NEW` `IF NEW.is_continued IS NULL
      THEN NEW.is_continued := 'false';
    END IF;`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that was an oversight of mine.